# When viewing bounties, non-bounty questions should not appear via the '1 new question' link

Tags: bug, status-completed, live-refresh, new-nav, bountied-tab

[image]

As you can see in the above image, after clicking `1 new question`, the `Long comments can break layout` question appeared - this should not happen preferably.

Please could either:

- the new question web sockets be disabled for that page or
- only show the 'x new questions` box if the new question(s) are bountied?

Comment: No idea if this is a bug or feature request

Comment: I also posted about this on [StackOverflow's meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303279/bounties-page-updates-with-new-activity-for-non-bounty-questions?cb=1), I think it's more likely a bug than a feature.

Answer (score 1):

this should be fixed now, but please double check

Comment: I'll try to see if I can get it to happen again -- it's more about right time right place :P BTW is new nav still active on MSE? Because I've got it on SO but not MSE...?